# How to load by partition into spark without knowing database table schema

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I am trying to load a 40 million large table into spark using JDBC connection. Clearly, load by partition is the answer to this.

Problem is that I do not know the schema of the table I need to load or which column to partition by. So how do I determine this from within spark?

```
val s_log = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
.option("url", "jdbc:mysql://impused?user=***&password=***")
.option("dbtable", "s_log")
.option("numPartitions", "500")
.option("partitionColumn", ??? no idea)
.option("lowerbound", ??? no idea)
.option("upperbound", ??? no idea)
.load()
```

Answer (score -1):

What you must know is the `table` name, in this case "s_log" so you can just execute this query:

```
DESCRIBE s_log;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'databasename' AND TABLE_NAME ='s_log'
```

Comment: But it does not give you minimum and maximum value of the column you need to choose ?

Comment: The output of the query are the column names. Once you've got the name you can just query "select max(column) from table"

Comment: How would you do it from spark ? The code is not working !